# 400 Bad Request, in wordpress theme development, wp_ajax

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, theme-development, ajax, wp-admin

As Salamu Alaikum,
I am developing a theme and I have tried every way of getting a successful ajax request and it is still showing me the 400 bad request error. And there is no solution I found going through one after one question in StackOverflow and Wordpress StackExchange.

Here is the ping.js file from where ajax call has been made.

```
jQuery('area').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var product_id = jQuery(this).attr('href');
      Ping(product_id);
    });
            function Ping(product_id) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                    //cache: false,
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //dataType: "html",
                    data: { 'action':'my_action'}, 
                    success: onSuccesPing,
                    error: onErrorPing,
                });

            }
            function onSuccesPing(data,status) {
                alert(data);
            }
            function onErrorPing(data,status) {

            }
```

And in functions.php I have the following code

```
function enqueue_scripts() {
        wp_register_script('ajax-script',  get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/ping.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); 
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script'); // jQuery will be included automatically
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts'); 
function my_action() { 
    echo 'woooo';
?>

<?php die(); }
add_action(' wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action(' wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

Even if I remove the whole wp_ajax_{functions} of functions.php, it gives me the same thing. Seems like the request is not being able to hit the wo_ajax_{function}. Please, Help I have spent a whole 8 hours behind this but still no solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Remove space before wp_ajax from **add_action(' wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action'); add_action(' wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');**

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, you have added extra white space before `wp_ajax` action. remove space from actions `' wp_ajax_my_action'` and `' wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action'`. because of extra space before ajax request, showing the 400 bad request error.
You should use :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brother.

Comment: Welcome Brother!